# Indexout of bound exception

Tags: android

I am trying to use Geocoder for getting a location by passing latitude and longitude.  But I always get an array size of zero and the error `indexoutofboundexception index 0 size 0`.

I tried with different longitude and latitude values.

```
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();


                    List<Address> address;

                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale
                            .getDefault());

                    try {
                        address = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                        if (address != null && address.size() >= 0) {
                            loc = address.get(0).getAdminArea();

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude
                                            + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\nLocation: "
                                            + loc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no data",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // System.out.println("size of ade " + address.size());
                        // System.out.println(address.get(0).getLocality());
                        // loc = address.get(0).getLocality();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // \n is for new line
//                  Toast.makeText(
//                          getApplicationContext(),
//                          "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude
//                                  + "\nLong: " + longitude + "\nLocation: "
//                                  + loc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

here is the stack trace

```
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at com.example.gpstracker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 14:01:06.592: E/AndroidRuntime(11006):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is my mistake?  Thanks.

Comment: what coordinates have you been trying?

Comment: You shouldn't get an exception from this code... Do you use `address.get(0)` anywhere else?

Comment: indexoutofbound means an arrayoverflow, at least to me, do you have one anywhere? then make it a bit bigger ^^

Comment: @koljaTM recently i tried with Latitude: 31.6690981 Longitude: -8.004252199999996

Comment: @Sam i am not using address.get(0) other than this place

Comment: Click [edit] and post your entire stack trace.

Comment: @Sam i have added the stack trace

Comment: Thanks, what is line 54? `at com.example.gpstracker.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)`

Comment: @Sam  loc = address.get(0).getAdminArea(); this is at line 54

Comment: That doesn't make sense because you have the conditional `address.size() > 0`... Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: Did you tried the lat / lng hardcoded. And put a breakpoint at if (address != null && address.size() > 0) {

And see what the actual result is. Because it seems it has data because it is passing the if statement. Besides that you sure you have the right permissions and internet connection?

Comment: @Sam yea i have cleaned the project. each time before running i will clean the project

Comment: @QVDev i have tried placing the breakpoint and debugging it. i will always get an empty array.. "[]".

Comment: Remarkable it passes the if statement anyways. Do you have more surrounding code?

Comment: @QVDev that is what i am also looking, how it passing the if statement. line no 54 is       loc = address.get(0).getAdminArea();

Comment: What result does the following code give you?
https://gist.github.com/QVDev/52c226911d393e6360c6
Try that and remove you're old code or put this new code in a new method. I know it is kind of different but this code works for sure.

Comment: Please post the entire `onClick()` method, so we can see more of what's happenning.

Comment: @QVDev location area..

Comment: @Sam added onclick method

Comment: Weird, I was hoping you were using an empty catch block like `catch (IOException e) {}` which would explain it.  You aren't ignoring any orange errors from `e.printStackTrace()` are you?

Comment: @Sam this is the orange errors i am getting 03-26 14:40:24.001: W/dalvikvm(11902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (address != null && address.size() >= 0) {
```

to

```
 if (address != null && address.size() > 0) {
```

Comment: +1 Ha, that would do it. (This wasn't the [original code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15639091/6) in the question.)

Comment: @cserepj i tried that. it will display only the toast message saying "no data"

Comment: @user2143817 There could be many reasons why `address` is empty.  From [Geocoder's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html): "The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in the core android framework. The Geocoder query methods will return an empty list if there no backend service in the platform. Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists." and from `getFromLocation()`: "Returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available."

Comment: Yes, you should call GeoCoder.isPresent()